# Rails - How to save form data and retrieve it when user navigates back to the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

This is more of a conceptual question, but I've included some code to make it easier to understand.  I have a form to create an auction, one of the fields on the form is to select from a collection of documents.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.fields_for :document_attributes do |b| %>
    <%= b.label "Choose a Document" %><br>
    <%= b.collection_select :id, Document.where(user_id: current_user.id), :id, :title, prompt: true %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

An Auction `has_one :document`

A user can either select a document from the dropdown, or go to the documents page and create a new document.

`<%= link_to "Add New Document", all_documents_path(current_user.id) %>`

The problem is, if and when a user navigates to the create document page, they lose all their progress on the auction form page.

How can I save the progress they’ve made on the auction form, and be able to come right back to it after a user has created a new document?

Comment: Maybe you can use nested form?

Comment: The document isn't a file, it just has a title and text that can be pasted into a text area.  I'd rather not nest this form, as the auction form is long enough as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You could give them a save and add document button option that would hit your save action on the auction, then forward them to the add document route.